# .net maui blazor - Show image from android internal storage

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui, maui-blazor

Im using the .net maui blazor to get the device to take a photo, then as its taken it, i wish to display it on the screen so the user can see what image they have just taken.

I found on the MS docs how to take a photo using `var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();`

and then it gives a simple way of storing this to the cache of the device using:

```
async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
{
    // canceled
    if (photo == null)
    {
        PhotoPath = null;
        return;
    }
    // save the file into local storage
    var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
    using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
    using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
        await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

    PhotoPath = newFile;
}
```

Which i understand, its generating the file path, using the base class of FileResult that holds the steam, and then creating and dumping that onto the device.

However my issue comes form trying to display that image in the html.

I saw one Stackoverflow suggestion using

```
myImg.Source = PhotoPath;//Show on the front page
```

But I believe this is just for .net maui,

With the blazor and HTML elements I would like it to be using the

I'm currently storing the string in the PhotoPath, and then calling it from the HTML element as

```
<img src="@PhotoPath" ...>
```

but its just coming up with the "image not found" icon, im not sure if i have to set up a  reader to go in and grab that image, and then display it though bytes.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" @onclick="@(() => TakePhoto())">Take Photo</button>

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhotoPath))
{
    <img width="320" height="320" src="@PhotoPath" />

}


@code
{
private string PhotoPath;
    private string localFilePath = "";

public async void TakePhoto()
    {
        if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
        {
            FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();
            if (photo == null)
            {
                //PhotoPath = null;
                return;
            }

localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
 using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);
 await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);

 //additional

            sourceStream.Dispose();
            localFileStream.Dispose();
            var imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(localFilePath);
            PhotoPath = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            PhotoPath = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", PhotoPath);
                StateHasChanged();

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `variable` and assign the value after storing the photo.

Different from local image , we need to convert the data to `Base64 string` with bytes and  specify its format , so that it could be displayed properly .

##### Sample code

```
@if (imageSource is not null)
{
    <div>
        <img src="@imageSource" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
}

@code {
    private string? imageSource;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var newFile = filePath;
        var imageBytes  = File.ReadAllBytes(newFile);
        imageSource = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        imageSource = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageSource);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are searching for .net Maui And reached here like me Than it Might Help You..

```
 async void TakePhotoCicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string sGpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);


     if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
     {
         FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

         if (photo != null)
         {
             // save the file into local storage
             string localFilePath = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);

             using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
             using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

             await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);

             string ReadFilePath = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);

             imgFoto.Source = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);

             GoNext.IsVisible = true;
         }
     }

 }
```

**imgFoto.Source = Path.Combine(sGpath, photo.FileName);**

Here this is the value where you need to change